# Is there a way to filter out specific error messages using Django Logging? eg UncompressableFileError

Tags: python, django, logging, filter, sentry

Is there a way to filter out specific error messages using Django Logging? eg UncompressableFileError

Would like to stop these errors being sent to Sentry.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a `Filter` on the Sentry handler which checks for the type of errors you want to filter out, and return `False` to drop them. Roughly:

```
def sentry_filter(record):
    return 'UncompressableFileError' not in record.getMessage()
```

and then

```
sentry_handler.addFilter(sentry_filter)
```

This might need to be tweaked depending on where the string occurs - e.g. in message or traceback

Answer (score 0):

Found this in the end from another answer on SA which works with Raven:

[Is there a way to filter out specific error messages using Django Logging? eg UncompressableFileError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72632464/is-there-a-way-to-filter-out-specific-error-messages-using-django-logging-eg-un/72636645#72636645)

```
class MyExceptionType(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        super(MyExceptionType, self).__init__(message)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SENTRY_CONFIG'] = {
    'ignore_exceptions': [MyExceptionType],
}
```